# Overriding variable property with different type

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, var

I have a variable 'children', which is just a list of participants. Can one please explain how can I override a variable with one type to a property with another type.

Here is a code:

```
class ParticipantsListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var participantsTableView: UITableView!

    // Error on next line: Property 'children' with type '[Child]?' cannot override a property with type '[UIViewController]'
    var children: [Child]?
    var trackingHelper = TrackingHelper()
    var modelHelper = ModelHelper.shared
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple. You can't do that. `UIViewController`, the class you're inheriting from, has this property under lock and key. You'll need to create yourself a new solution depending on what you're trying to achieve:

#### Condition A: `Child` is a subclass of `UIViewController`

In this case, you want a way to make the child view controllers of `ParticipantsListViewController` always conform to `Child`. One way to do this would be the following computed property:

```
var listChildren: [Child] {
    return children.filter { $0 is Child }
}
```

#### Condition B: `Child` is NOT a subclass of `UIViewController`

You're trying to override something that the system needs to be there. Things in the `children` array have to be instances or subclasses of `UIViewController`. It's strict.

Your solution here is easy. Name the property differently and get rid of the override. Sure, it won't have the nicest, simplest name `children`, but that's the way it goes.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't have `children` property with your custom type since property with the **same name** is already property of `UIViewController` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621452-children)) which is superclass of your view controller so your subclass has this property too.

So, you have to use other name for your variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using protocol conformance for your `Child` view controllers as demonstrated here:

```
import UIKit

protocol ChildProtocol { }

class SomeViewController: UIViewController, ChildProtocol { }

class ParticipantsListViewController: UIViewController {
    override var children: [UIViewController] {
        return self.children.filter { viewController in viewController is ChildProtocol }
    }
}
```

So long as the view controllers that you wish to be a `Child` conform to `ChildProtocol`, then they will be returned via the children override.

Comment: *which is just a list of participants*... this doesn't look like array of controllers

Comment: you probably want `super`, not `self`, in that return statement.